# do while loop if username exists in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, do-while

I'm trying to get the following function to return an altered username with a number appended. The number should increment by one for each of the identical usernames. I'm calling the wordpress function username_exists() to check for matches. Please help. Thanks

```
function change_username($name) {

  $q = username_exists($name);
  $i = 0;

   do {
       $name = $name . $i++;
   } while ($q);

   return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "save" the result of the calculation. In addition, you have to keep the fixed part of the name stored separately. Do both by using a `while` loop instead like this:

```
$baseName = $name;
$i = 0;

while(username_exists($name)) {
    $name = $baseName . (++$i);
}

return $name;
```

Comment: With this solution, how could I concatenate a separator character to differentiate between '$baseName' and '$i' for example '$baseName . '+' . (++$i);' doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobiOjera: If you start going that way, it may be more readable to use `sprintf`, e.g. `$name = sprintf('%s-%d', $baseName, ++$i)`. Otherwise it's just string concatenation, `$baseName.'+'.(++$i)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_username($name) {

  $q = username_exists($name);
  $i = 0;

   while($q){
       $name = $name . $i++;
       $q = username_exists($name);
   }

   return $name;
}
```